# For a function comma(s), with s being a string containing lowercase letters and numbers, how can I add a comma after each number in Python?

Tags: python

The function can be comma(s), where s is a string argument containing lowercase letters and numbers, and it must return a string with a comma after each number but not if the number is the last character. E.g comma("sr43rt4d4") must return sr43,rt4,d4
In Python

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Unfortunately this is not a code-writing or tutorial service, and we ask that you include a [mcve] with _code_ for what you've already tried based on your own research, and what went wrong with your attempts

Comment: Sorry, that is noted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex that getting all digit followed by lower case character then replace each value returned from the regex with the same value with , in between the result.

```
import re

s = "sr43rt4d4"
for i in re.findall(r"\d[a-z]", s):
    s = s.replace(i, "{},{}".format(*i))
print(s)
```

Output

```
'sr43,rt4,d4'
```